# How to check linearity of a variable without plots/graphs in R?

Tags: r, bioinformatics, modeling

I'm running a longitudinal study comparing patients with a lung growth which either developed into cancer (cancer_status = 1) or didn't (= 0). Here is some example randomly-generated data in the same format as the study:

| patient_ID* | cancer_status | time_to_outcome | cpg_1 | cpg_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | -532 | 0.49578632 | 0.9301869 |
| 1 | 1 | -121 | 0.51134914 | 0.9496315 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0.51665110 | 0.9535245 |
| 2 | 0 | -564 | 0.13605940 | 0.8912563 |
| 2 | 0 | -423 | 0.09577919 | 0.7950609 |
| 2 | 0 | -266 | 0.13383500 | 0.8726626 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 0.11834631 | 0.8492904 |
| 3 | 1 | -128 | 0.35097042 | 0.9727214 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 0.53230504 | 0.9643870 |
| etc... |  |  |  |  |

*Each patient had multiple measurements/samples taken.

Following [this tutorial](https://fernandashackenhaar.github.io/LMMs/) on linear mixed effects modelling, I'm trying to model the effect of cancer_status on each cpg variable over time (i.e., time_to_outcome, measured in days).

The tutorial starts by checking whether the variables are linear (an assumption of the linear mixed effects model), by plotting a general additive mixed model (GAMM):

```r
library(gamm4)
library(splines)

# this GAMM adjusts for multiple measurements being taken from each 
# patient, but doesn't adjust for anything else like sex or age:
cpg1_gamm_cases <- gamm4(cpg_1 ~ 1 + s(time_to_outcome), 
    data = df[df$cancer_status == 1, ],
random = ~ (1|patient_ID)
)

plot(cpg1_gamm_cases$gam,
shade = TRUE,
shift = cpg1_gamm_cases$gam$coefficients[1],
    ylab = 'CpG_1 cases',
    residuals = TRUE,
    pch = 20,
    pages = 1)

cpg1_f <- fitted(cpg1_gamm_cases$mer)
cpg1_r <- resid(cpg1_gamm_cases$mer)
plot(x = cpg1_f, 
    y = cpg1_r,
    xlab = "Fitted values",
    ylab = "Residuals",
       cex = 0.3)
abline(lm(resid(cpg1_gamm_cases$mer) ~ fitted(cpg1_gamm_cases$mer)))
```

result 1: [image: plot of cpg_1 values against time_to_outcome values]

result 2: [image: plot of model residuals against model fitted values]

The above plots show there is no clear linear relationship between cpg_1 and time. (This is expected because the data was randomly generated). Therefore in this case, it probably wouldn't make sense to run a linear mixed effects model on this variable.

**The problem is: In the study, I don't have just cpg_1 and cpg_2 variables to model, I need to model ~850,000 different cpg variables.** (For context, each CpG is a different site on the genome, with a continuous value somewhere between 0 and 1 - this represents the average DNA methylation at the site).

**Every source I've seen says to test the linearity assumption of linear models by plotting your data and looking at it, as above. However, I can't possibly generate and look at 850,000 different graphs. Is there a simple check for linearity (like a function) which can be run in R?**

(Somewhat unrelated: there probably should be a simpler way to do this than to run 850k separate models, but this is the approach most published studies seem to be taking for this type of data.)

Comment: It seems that your 0 time is the time of last observation, with the earliest `time_to_outcome ` representing when the lung growth was detected and with `cancer_status` in _all_ rows representing status at the _last_ observation. If that's the case, then you should be using a form of survival analysis rather than this type of GAM. If your primary interest is the association of CpG site methylation with time between lung-growth detection and cancer, that could remove the need for mixed modeling, simplify the handling of time, and avoid the bias from ignoring right-censoring of event times.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting this bias EdM. Although it's not shown in the example, in the real dataset we do know the time point at which the cancer occurred (`cancer_status` is a case or control variable, which I should probably rename!) The GAM model is used here to check for linearity whereas the 'main' analysis will be something like linear mixed effects. Would you say GAM requires different input variables from `cancer_status` and `time_to_outcome` to avoid bias in the linearity check? (Edit: survival analysis does also sound like a good option here)

Comment: Main bias risk is treating cancer status as case/control. Unless everyone was followed for the same duration that leads to bias. See any review on censoring in survival data, like [this](https://doi.org/10.1146/annurev.publhealth.18.1.83). Also, requiring linear changes in methylation over time is very limiting. Depending on how you envision the association between CpG methylation and outcome, you might consider CpG methylation as a time-varying covariate to be fit flexibly in a Cox model with a regression spline. If you only have 13 cases, however, it will be hard to get robust results.

Comment: Great, thanks for this - will do some reading around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given how large your sample is nearing 1M CpG variables, it would surely be impractical as you have described to generate and visually inspect individual plots for each variable. Using statistical tests or functions in R would help you quantify linearity while also giving you that visual you desire.

Computing the correlation between each CpG variable and the time-to-outcome would be a good approach that can be evaluated by [Pearson's correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient). This is great for a linear correlation, however, it falls short when we begin working with non-linear correlations, which you might have here.

In this case the [Bruesch-Pagan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breusch%E2%80%93Pagan_test) test from the lmtest package would be good to test non-linearity. This test checks for heteroskedasticity, which can be an indicator of nonlinearity in the relationship.

The approach that I would take to this in R would be:

1. Calculate Pearson's coefficients for each CpG variable against the time-to-outcome.
2. Perform the Bruesch-Pagan test on a simple linear model for each CpG variable.

```r
library(lmtest)

# Function to test linearity for a given variable
test_linearity <- function(variable_name, df) {
  # Create a linear model
  lm_model <- lm(reformulate("time_to_outcome", 
                  response = variable_name), data = df)

  # Calculate Pearson's correlation
  correlation <- cor(df[[variable_name]], df$time_to_outcome)

  # Perform the Breusch-Pagan test
  bp_test <- bptest(lm_model)

  # Return results
  list(correlation = correlation, bp_test = bp_test$p.value)
}

# Apply the function to all CpG variables
linearity_results <- lapply(names(df)[grepl("cpg_", names(df))], 
    test_linearity, df = df)
```

This script will return a list of correlation coefficients and p-values for the Breusch-Pagan test for each CpG variable. You can then decide on a threshold for what you consider linear based on these metrics.

This would be my simple approach and solution. For running separate models for each CpG site you might want to consider dimensionality reduction or multivariate models that can handle multiple predictors simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Using grep + lapply to apply this to every column is a good idea as well.

Comment: A big statistical problem in this instance is that the times to events are right censored. Some individuals had not yet been diagnosed with cancer as of the last observation time. The code in the question evidently omits all those individuals: `data = df[df$cancer_status == 1,]`. That omission runs a risk of severe bias in the resulting estimates.

Answer (score 5):

You can detect many forms of nonlinear relationships, or lack thereof, using a global test of association known as Hoeffding's D.  In R you can run the test using the Hmisc library and using either the varclus() or the hoeffd() command.  For more information see

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Hmisc/versions/5.1-1/topics/hoeffd

or

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/Hmisc/versions/5.1-1/topics/varclus